# Entity Framework sets property to null when saving

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I got a weird issue I can't explain.

I'm working with EF here. Got a method that copies some values from a wrapper object into the object I already have in the database. The object in the database has to be updated with the values in the wrapper object.

Here's the code:

```
private void UpdateAudit(AuditWrapper audit, DatabaseAccess dbAccess)
{
        var foundAudit = dbAccess.Audits.Include("Auditors").SingleOrDefault(_ => _.Audit_ID == audit.Audit_ID);    
        if(foundAudit != null)
        {
            foundAudit.Auditorennamen = audit.Auditorennamen;
            foundAudit.AuditTarget = audit.AuditTarget;
            foundAudit.Scopes = audit.Scopes;
            foundAudit.Location = audit.Location;
            foundAudit.Address = audit.Address;

            foundAudit.Auditors.Clear();

            foreach (var item in audit.Auditors)
            {
                var usr = dbAccess.Users.SingleOrDefault(_ => _.Username == item.Username);
                if (usr != null)
                {
                    var uta = dbAccess.User_To_Audit.Create();
                    uta.Function = item.Function;
                    uta.User = usr;
                    uta.Audit_GeneratedID = foundAudit.GeneratedID;
                    uta.Audit = foundAudit;
                    foundAudit.Auditors.Add(uta);
                }   
            }
        }

        dbAccess.SaveChanges();
    }
```

In the `User_To_Audit` object the `Audit` is set to null, even though it wasn't null when I selected it from the database.

No idea why it is set to null when I use `db.SaveChanges()`.

Well, I don't know if the property is really null, but I can tell it saves null into the database in the foreign key column.

I've already tried to only set the GeneratedID or only set the Audit or set none of them. Every time the same effect.

```
[ForeignKey("Audit")]
public int Audit_GeneratedID { get; set; }
public virtual Audit Audit { get; set; }
```

Please help

update:
`Audit` has a `List<User_To_Audit>`.
`User_To_Audit` has a reference to the `Audit` it belongs to.

```
public class Audit
{
    [Key]
    public int GeneratedID { get; set; }
    [Index("Audit_ID", IsUnique = true)]
    public int Audit_ID { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
    public virtual List<User_To_Audit> Auditors { get; set; }
}

public class User_To_Audit
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Audit")]
    public int Audit_GeneratedID { get; set; }
    public virtual Audit Audit { get; set; }
    public virtual AuditorFunction Function { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what this method foundAudit.Auditors.Clear(); do? it seems clearing Auditors?

Comment: Auditors is a List<User_To_Audit>. It's just the standard clear-method of list.
What i want to do: Clear this list and add all elements from the Wrapper-Class.(see foreach after)

Comment: what is the FK between User_To_Audit and Audit? Where is it set? Otherwise relationship fixup might remove the navigation property upon adding to the context.

Comment: oh, just found it. is generatedId actually the key of the Audit object in the database?

Comment: The Audit has a List<User_To_Audit>. 
The User_To_Audit has a reference to the Audit it belongs to and additionally the FK (see 2nd code-snippet)

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Yes excatly

Comment: shouldn't be the uta.Audit_GeneratedID assigned to foundAudit.Audit_ID ? am I missing something?

Comment: No. Audit has a GeneratedID(Primarykey, autoincrement) and Audit_ID(Unique). The FK (uta.Audit_GeneratedID) points to the PK of Audit(GeneratedID).

Comment: Please see the updated question

Comment: I'd move the SaveChanges to inside the null check. Then breakpoint there and see if it is ever null at that point.

Then also, something to investigate is the convention aspect of EF. I don't think it is mapping the ForeignKey to the GeneratedID of the Audit, due to the underscore in the name of the FK property. Try removing the underscore and check the mapping, or explicitly configure it using fluentApi.

Comment: Tried both things, still the same error.

Comment: can you try setting only the Audit object and remove the id assignment?

Comment: I've already done that too(see question). Sometimes EF is just frustrating...